# Can someone send the ReadInt32 to Write Process Memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, offset, cheat-engine

I am trying to write to process memory, so I copied the code from a video.
But this video does not show the function "ReadInt32", can someone send me to finally be able to run this application?

**ReadInt32(process, (IntPtr)address)**

```
public static long GetRealAddress(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress, int[] offsets)
    {
        var address = baseAddress.ToInt64();
        foreach (var offset in offsets)
        {
            address = ReadInt32(process, (IntPtr)address) + offset;

        }
        return address;
    }
```

Error Highlighted in Code:

[image: Error PrintScreen]

Pointer:  *(The type is float)*

[image: Pointer here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr handle, IntPtr baseAddress,
    byte[] buffer, int size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);


public static int ReadInt32(IntPtr processHandle, IntPtr address)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

    ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address,
       buffer, buffer.Length, out IntPtr bytesRead);

    // if this gives the wrong value:
    // Array.Reverse(buffer);
    var myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
    return myInt;
}
```